# Android Studio doesn't generate bundle

Tags: android-studio, android-app-bundle

I've been trying to build a new version of my app bundle and it won't build it with the same key.
I click on Build>Generate Signed Bundle or APK...>select Android App Bundle>click Next, then I select my key, I put the same key store password, the same key alias, check for the key store path twice just in case, click on Next>select release>Finish and nothing happens. I don't get an error or any kind of prompt, just nothing.

How do I fix this?

**edit: I found the answer**, the alias wasn't the same, Android Studio won't even try to build a new version if the key alias is different

Comment: Have you checked in your destination folder to check if the apk is there or not?
You can change it to your desktop and see if the apk is generated

Comment: I did, I made a new folder and after building the bundle the folder is still empty.

Comment: the key thing worked for me. you should create an answer for it.

Answer (score 13):

Had to uncheck the "Export Encrypted key...." option.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn' make any sense but it works

Comment: Yep that was the issue for me...and I tried it on chipmunk

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing .keystore suffix from key path